# How to import and use different packages of the same name

Tags: go, package

For example, I want to use both  text/template and html/template in one source file.
But the code below throw errors.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template" // template redeclared as imported package name
    "html/template" // template redeclared as imported package name
)

func handler_html(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t_html, err := html.template.New("foo").Parse(`{{define "T"}}Hello, {{.}}!{{end}}`)
    t_text, err := text.template.New("foo").Parse(`{{define "T"}}Hello, {{.}}!{{end}}`)

}
```

Answer (score 342, accepted):

```
import (
    "text/template"
    htemplate "html/template" // this is now imported as htemplate
)
```

Read more about it [in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations).

Comment: Any convention on how we should name the imported package? Short and small case is general recommendation. But what in case we can't come up with any meaningful short name? Which one is preferable - `multi_word` or `multiWord`?

Answer (score 42):

*Answer by Mostafa is correct however it demands some explanation. Let me try to answer it.*

**Your example code doesn't work because you're trying to import two packages with the same name, which is: " template ".**

```
import "html/template"  // imports the package as `template`
import "text/template"  // imports the package as `template` (again)
```

**Importing is a declaration statement:**

- You can't declare the same name (*terminology: identifier*) in the same scope.
- In Go, `import` is a declaration, and its scope is the file that's trying to import those packages.
- It doesn't work because of the same reason that you can't declare variables with the same name in the same block.

**The following code works:**

```
package main

import (
    "text/template"
    htemplate "html/template"
)

func main() {
    template.New("foo").Parse(`{{define "T"}}Hello, {{.}}!{{end}}`)
    htemplate.New("foo").Parse(`{{define "T"}}Hello, {{.}}!{{end}}`)
}
```

The code above gives two different names to the imported packages with the same name. So, there are now two different identifiers that you can use: `template` for the `text/template` package and `htemplate` for the `html/template` package.

[You can check it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TwMU1BAv3by).