# How to use "html/template" and "text/template" at the same time in Golang

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I'm sending emails with Go, and I'm parsing both the subject and the HTML body from templates stored in a database.

For the subject I wouldn't want `t.Parse()` to escape html entities since it isn't HTML, just plain text, but for the body this is exactly the behavior I want.

How do I do both in the same file?

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same issue here. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408646/how-to-import-and-use-different-packages-of-the-same-name-in-go-language>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume the issue you are facing is the conflicting imports between the identically-named `template` packages.

In this case, use a named import for one or both packages to access its members via another name in the source file:

```
package mypackage

import (
    htmltemplate "html/template"
    texttemplate "text/template"
)
```

Now write code which refers to the template packages as usual, but use the alias names `htmltemplate` or `texttemplate` in place of `template`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you